# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Property 'password' doesn't exist. pg-promise

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

I am using pg-promise.

I am having an issue trying to insert the following Javascript array:

```
[ { email: 'test1@gmail.com', password: 'test2' },
  { email: 'tes2t@gmx.com', password: 'test'3 },
  { email: 'test4@gmail.com', password: 'test4' },
  { email: 'test4@yahoo.com.ar', password: 'test5' }]
```

Using the following:

```
async function insertDB(data){
  const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['email', 'password'], {table: 'users'});
  console.log(data)
  const query = pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs);

  db.none(query)
      .then(data => {
          logger.info(" Query success: ", data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      logger.warn(" Query error: ", error);
  });
}
```

and I get

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Property 'password' doesn't exist.**

```
**data.password = undefined**
**data[0] = { email: 'test1@gmail.com', password: 'test2' }**
```

How can I insert this data into my postgresdb?

Comment: Side note 1: Never store passwords in cleartext in the database. In fact, never store passwords in the database full stop. (Store appropriately-salted hashes instead.)

Comment: Side note 2: Why are you using `then` and `catch` in an `async` function? The point of `async` functions is that you can use `await` and logical-flow structures like `try`/`catch`.

Comment: It seems fairly clear from the error that one of the entries in `data` doesn't have a property called `password` (despite your array shown at the top having a password on all of its objects).

Comment: Side note 3: That's not a "Javascript JSON array". It's just an array. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you! The passwords won't be in clear text, it's just for the purpose of the demo.Re async: I just took that example from the pg-promise docs and added it to my code, thanks for the heads up though I didn't know that, will fix.

Comment: Good point also on note 3, thanks again will update the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Do you know how I can let it continue with the insert if a password is missing?

Comment: @Sledro What do you want to insert in place of a missing password?

Comment: Just prefilter the data: `data = data.filter(({email, password}) => email && password);` That will create a new array containing only the objects from the original array that have non-blank `email` and `password` properties. https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/3wLk9n46/ (There I'm assuming you don't want to insert that record at all.)

Comment: Cheers T.J! This filter method worked nicely also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// should create columnsets only once:
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['email', 'password'], {table: 'users'});

function insertDB(data) {

  // wrapping it into a function is safer, for error-reporting via query methods:
  const query = ()=> pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs);

  db.none(query)
      .then(data => {
          // data = null always here, no point displaying it
          logger.info('Query success:', data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      logger.warn('Query error:', error);
  });
}
```

And your function doesn't need `async` in this case.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Property 'password' doesn't exist.

You are confusing the JavaScript compiler, declaring the function as `async`, and then throwing an error synchronously while generating the insert, due to missing property `password`.

And if you want to insert some records without password, with `null`, for example, define your columnset like this:

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    'email',
    {name: 'password', def: null}
], {table: 'users'});
```

Other than that, type [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) is ultimately flexible, see the documentation for each contained [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html).

**EXTRA**

And if you want to use server-side `DEFAULT` value for missing passwords, you can provide it, with the help of [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting):

```
const DEFAULT = {rawType: true, toPostgres: ()=> 'DEFAULT'};
```

And then your `password` column can be defined like this:

```
{name: 'password', def: DEFAULT}
```

And there are many alternatives, with properties `init` and `mod` supported by [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the awesome lib ;) That def: null part worked magic.

Comment: @Sledro Extended with an extra example ;)